# How can I display a coordinate grid in the map canvas?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I want a live renderizing grid on the map canvas in QGIS, during processing, not on the map composer. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 17):

'View > Decorations > Grid'.  The Grid properties allows you to set line type and interval, as well as any annotations (such as lat/lon).  This is purely an overlay that you can't interact with and doesn't render in the print composer.

Comment: wow that was easy. don't know how I missed it. Thanks a lot.